# Cómo hacer drag and drop de objetos (figuras geométricas)

Tags: c#, windows-forms, objeto

Estoy necesitando hacer en un Winform un aplicativo que permita con un click tomar un objeto y arrastrarlo.

Para empezar puede ser figuras geométricas básicas como un círculo.
Todo eso programado en Visual C# en un WinForm.

Gracias.

Saludos.

Maxi.

Answer (score 0):

Para realizar esa tarea vas a necesitar utilizar eventos de ratón: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/desktop/winforms/input-mouse/events?view=netdesktop-5.0

Eventos como `MouseDown` que detecta cuando el usuario hace click o `MouseMove` que comprueba la posición del cursor en la pantalla puede estar interesante.

Se me ocurre que tengas creados los objetos e instanciados en el formulario en un lateral. El usuario podría hacer click sobre uno e inmediatamente este se desplazaría en conjunto con las posiciones x,y del ratón. Cuando volviese a pulsar, el objeto dejaría de actualizar su posición. Podría ser una primera aproximación, aunque hay varias formas de conseguirlo.

Un saludo